# Error in linking mysql and netbeans data

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I am working with mysql and Netbeans java for my school project. Whenever I try to register the details to the sql, I get this error `My SqlSyntaxErrorException:Unknown Column " [the data in the text field] in 'field list'"`
Here's my code:

```
  int age = Integer.parseInt(AgeTF.getText());
  String name=NameTF.getText();
  String id=IDTF.getText();
  String dob=DobTF.getText();
  String address=AddressTF.getText();

    try {           
        Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
        String database = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/final";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "root", "sanchit");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "insert into aadhar values ( '" + id + "', " + name + ", '" + dob + "' ,  '" + age + "'  , '" + address + "' );" ;
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        }
    catch( Exception e){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"" + e);
    }
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"You have been registered!");
```

Please help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't protect **name** with simple quotes :

Write `'" + name + "'` instead of `" + name + "`

```
String sql = "insert into aadhar values ( '" + id + "', '" + name + "', '" + dob + "' ,  '" + age + "'  , '" + address + "' );" ;
```